# How can I react to a finished upload with <h:inputFile>?

Tags: file-upload, richfaces, ajax4jsf, jsf-2.2, wildfly

I'm using Richfaces-4.3.5 on Wildfly-8.0.0.CR1 here, migrating from `<rich:fileUpload>` which doesn't work with JSF-2.2/Servlet-3.0. I'm replacing it with this snippet:

```
<rich:popupPanel id="testPop" autosized="true">
    <h:form id="uploadF" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <h:inputFile value="#{bean.file}">
           <a4j:ajax listener="#{bean.storeFile()}" render="@form,:fileListTbl"
               oncomplete="#{rich:component('testPop')}.hide();" />
       </h:inputFile>
    </h:form>
</rich:popupPanel>
```

This works fine in that the `storeFile` method is called and I can access `bean.file` just fine. However, I'd like to close the `rich:popupPanel` when I'm done uploading, so I need to react to the success/complete events of the ajax request. But that doesn't seem possible - the popup stays visible and the response is clearly incomplete (indented for better readability):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<partial-response id="j_id1">
  <changes>
    <update id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0">
      <[CDATA[-1186354868983349335:-5499969782208038164]]>
    </update>
    <extension id="org.richfaces.extension"><render>@component</render></extension>
  </changes>
</partial-response>
```

Though the richfaces debug messages indicate the handlers *are* being called:

```
RichFaces: Received 'success' event from <input id=uploadF:j_idt1136 ...>
RichFaces: Received 'complete' event from <input id=uploadF:j_idt1136 ...>
```

So, simple question: how can I get the popup to close and the components to be re-rendered?

Answer (score 1):

i'm not sure if the problem is directly related to `a4j:ajax` or what's needed to be done to make it work with `a4j:ajax`, but the code below seems to work with `f:ajax`.

```
<h:form id="formId">
    <h:commandLink value="popup"
        onclick="#{rich:component('testPop')}.show(); return false;" />
</h:form>

<rich:popupPanel id="testPop" autosized="true">
    <h:form id="uploadF" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <h:inputFile value="#{bean.file}">
            <f:ajax listener="#{bean.storeFile()}" render="@form :fileListTbl"
                onevent="eventHandler"/>
        </h:inputFile>
    </h:form>
</rich:popupPanel>

<script>
    function eventHandler(event)
    {
        if (event.status == 'success')
        {
            #{rich:component('testPop')}.hide();
        }
    }
</script>
```